# bold a defined color

Tags: color

Here is one of my custom colors that is "light blue". Sometimes it comes up very skinny on the text

`\definecolor{lb}{RGB}{44, 139, 183}`

Is there an easier way to bold or thicken the font of a `\definecolor` such that I don't have to manually change every `\textcolor{lb}{}`to `\textcolor{lb}{\textbf{text goes here}}`?

Comment: A macro may work here.

Comment: `\newcommand{\textboldlb}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{lb}{#1}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By  "bolding" the color of some text, I assume you mean to give the text thicker strokes but without switching to bold-extended type.

If this assumption is correct, the following solution may be of interest to you.

[image]

Note that the bold colored parts have (almost) the same widths that the regular-weight colored parts have.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lb}{RGB}{44, 139, 183}
\newcommand\cl[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\bcl[2]{\textcolor{#1}{{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #2}}}

\begin{document}
\cl{lb}{Hello World.}

\bcl{lb}{Hello World.}

Hello World.

\cl{red}{Good bye.}

\bcl{red}{Good bye.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: oooh yes this is very relevant for me. What are `\cl[2]` and `\bcl[2]`? I see what they do, but I don't know what they are

Comment: @EvanKim - Those are parts of macro definitions. The macros’ names are `\cl` and `\bcl`, respectively? . Noticed the `\newcommand` directives that precede them? In both cases, the `[2]` particles mean that the macros take two arguments — the colt and the string to be colored.